# JavaFX DatePicker disable future dates

Tags: javafx, javafx-datepicker

I want to allow user to select date from DateChooser upto current date. How can I disable future dates in DatePicker of JavaFX?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set a DayCellFactory. This allows you to control essentially all style elements of the datepicker, including whether or not dates after a specified date are greyed out.

```
datePicker.setDayCellFactory(param -> new DateCell() {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(LocalDate date, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(date, empty);
            setDisable(empty || date.compareTo(LocalDate.now()) > 0 );
        }
    });
```

PS: any node that has cells in it (TableView, DatePicker, ListView etc) can have its `updateItem` method overridden, which allows you to configure the style of that cell based on its data. Use with caution, and always make sure you include the `super.updateItem()` that comes with it.

Comment: Thanks for extra information. what super.updateItem() does?

Comment: @Govind_das It invokes the super implementation of the method. [As documented](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html#updateItem(T,boolean)), you must call the super implementation otherwise the cell can break.